# Automate .net web app Deploy on several servers with load balancer

Tags: .net, deployment, web, load-balancing, citrix

I want to know if there is a way to deploy and publish a .net web app on several servers automatically.
we have a Citrix load balancer which on deploy time I should disable a few servers and copy the deploy package on disabled servers and after worm up enable them and do deployment for other servers.
is there any tools to do this process automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Inedo's [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/BuildMaster) (disclaimer: I work there). We actually have a number of users who do just this ([AllRecipes.com](http://inedo.com/buildmaster/case-studies/allrecipes), for example) - and you could probably accomplish exactly what you're trying to do using the free version of BuildMaster.